# How do i toggleClass on img in Gridview?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Im trying to enlarge pictures in a ASP gridview with jquery like this.

```
 <style>
  .enlargeImg{
   width:600px;
   height:600px;
 }

  </style> 
  <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('.pageContainer').on('click','img', function () {
           $(this).toggleClass('.enlargeImg');
           });

        });
   </script>
```

I hit the picture alright(can call an alert), but i can not get the toggleclass to work. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass('.enlargeImg');` you have an extra dot here! It should be `$(this).toggleClass('enlargeImg');`

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the extra dot when using toggleClass (`.enlargeImg`), just use `enlargeImg`.

**p.s.** I reduced the size of your image in css so that it fits inside the stack snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pageContainer').on('click', 'img', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('enlargeImg');
  });
});
```

```css
.basicImage{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.enlargeImg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='pageContainer'>
  <img src='https://kaggle2.blob.core.windows.net/datasets-images/152/327/43994ab64328703c9e656b04e6769947/dataset-original.jpg' class='basicImage' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, now it toggles, but the picture dosent respond to it. Should both classes be visible in Dev.tool. (Im new in this)?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't respond to it? What browser are you testing on and whats it actually doing?

Comment: I test in Chrome. Before toggle Class="normSize" After toggle class="normsize enlargeImg" . The picture isn't changing.

Comment: You will need to be able to access both classes yes

Comment: I works works this... var count = 0
               $('td').on('click', 'img', function () {
                  
                   if (count === 0) {
                       $(this).removeClass('normSize');
                       $(this).addClass('enlargeImg');
                       count++;
                   }
                   else {
                       $(this).removeClass('enlargeImg');
                       $(this).addClass('normSize');
                       count --;
                   }
                   
               }); but isn't that what toggleClass should do?